# How much fuel does the A380 use for taxiing before takeoff?

Tags: fuel, airbus-a380, cost

How much fuel does the A380 use for taxiing before takeoff and after landing? What does it cost at today's pricing?

Comment: Fuel costs vary by airport, country, and the airlines make deals with suppliers. You need to be more specific.  This link seems to generally cover what you ask https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/654/whats-the-typical-cost-and-its-breakdown-for-a-long-haul-commercial-flight?rq=1

Comment: Costs also depend on flight duration, passenger and cargo load, cabin crew numbers (salaries), airport taxes,  etc

Comment: @CrossRoads The [question you linked](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/661/65) answers this question. Possible duplicate.

Comment: You have two different questions here: the total cost of operating an A380 (probably [answered here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/654/62), as others have said), and the fuel required for taxiing (some information [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27918/62) but may not be exactly what you want). You might want to separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fuel burn

To be meaningful it's best to compare it. It is approximately 4 times what an A320 needs. So if both planes are fully booked, then in theory each passenger should pay the same for the taxi fuel -- it would become an issue though when the A380 has a low [load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_load_factor).

> Taxi Fuel is 1 170 lb for an average taxi duration of 12 min.

While for 12 minutes an A320 needs 300 lb.

#### Cost

As of 20 April 2018, it would cost Emirates -- the largest A380 operator -- about \$360 for a 12 min taxi in Dubai (less than a dollar per passenger).

But Dubai is a busy airport and as such the taxi duration can exceed 12 minutes. For example [Emirates 203](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAE203/history/20180420/2250Z/OMDB/KJFK) from a few days ago had a taxi time of 30 minutes. Operating a large airplane at a busy airport has its costs.

---

References:

- Airbus FCOMs for the A320 and A380
- [IATA fuel monitor](http://www.iata.org/publications/economics/fuel-monitor/Pages/index.aspx) (jet fuel cost varies by region).

Comment: *"1 170 lb for ... 12 min"* ...or pretty close to 100 lbs/minute.